# Event goal not getting recorded in Google analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I have set up a form through contact form 7 in a website. I have added Google analytics tracking code to set up a event goal on form submission. The event seems to get monitored on real time basics as in every form submission is triggering a event under the events tab. But the data seems to not get  recorded as a goal under the conversion tab. Can someone find a solution to this.

I have used the following tracking code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore (a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-18282623-2', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

and have set this code under the additional setting bar of contact form 7 to trigger the goal event:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'contact-form', 'click', 'submit form',1);"
```

where I have set

```
contact-form = Category
Action = click
Label = submit form
Value = 1
```

I have also tried with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18282623-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'
ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

along with:

```
on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contact-form', 'click', 'submit form']);"
```

Nothing seems to work. Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja3wy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVsV.png)

Comment: Debuggers are your friend. Install Firebug if you are on Firefox or open the Developer Tools in Chrome. The Network Tab will tell you if a call to GA has been sent, the console will display an error message in red if something is wrong with the javascript. IT will be easier to help you if you have a specific error message.

Comment: Your set up seems to be correct! How is your Goal setted up?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of how your goal is configured.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff i checked the network tab for any errors....but couldnt find any....

Comment: @nyuen  I have included the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal configuration includes a value greater than 1, but your event is sending a value exactly equal to 1. You will either need to adjust your goal configuration to convert when the value is equal to one or send a value for your event greater than one.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out bro... I just changed it now but it is still the same. Goal is getting triggered on real time basics but not getting saved.. Do you think it will take time for d data to get saved ?? like an hour or soo....

Comment: You don't see the data in GA change right away as it takes up to 24 hours to be processed. As long as you see the conversion in real time then you just need to wait a bit.